# When printing array it prints arbitrary symbols because I don't use all array values

Tags: c, arrays

I'm learning about arrays now in C. The problem that I'm having is that if i give an array a value of *for example*

```
char message[100], ch;
```

but then if I don't use all the chars it gives me some arbitrary symbols. *Example*

```
while(toupper(ch = getchar()) != '\n')
{
    message[i] = ch;
    i++;
}
```

If I would enter 50 chars press enter and then print it with:

```
for(i = 0; i <= 100 - 1; i++)
    printf("%c", message[i]);
```

It would print the 50 symbols and then 50 arbitrary sybols more.
in a previous question that I had someone told me that I don't have to use the 100 in the for loop, but with what I replace it.

I hope this gives a full picture of what my problem is, if not let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print 50 characters you need to make sure you have 50 characters in the `message` array,
The simplest way would be to use `i` itself.

You have to loop till `i` ( no. of entered characters <= 100 )

```
int j ;
for( j = 0; j < i; j++)
    printf("%c", message[j]);
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative method is to add:

```
message[i] = '\0';
```

after the while loop. This will add the terminating byte to `message`. Then when you output it you can use:

```
printf("%s", message);
```

instead of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

In C, strings are terminated with a null character, `'\0'`. So after your loop, you need to set the last character to that, and then you should print with a single `%s` (or `puts`) instead of  looping over the characters again.

```
while(toupper(ch = getchar()) != '\n')
{
    message[i] = ch;
    i++;
}
message[i] = '\0';
...
printf("%s\n", message);
// or
puts(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to handle this. You can either keep track of the length of the string, or you can use a "sentinel" value, which in C is traditionally a 0 byte (not a '0' character).

Given functions like this:

```
void print_null_terminated_string(char* s)
{
    while (*s != 0) {
        printf("%c", *s);
        ++s;
    }
}

void print_string_with_known_length(char* s, size_t length)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        printf("%c", s[i]);
    }
}
```

You could use them like this:

```
while(toupper(ch = getchar()) != '\n')
{
    message[i] = ch;
    i++;
}
message[i] = 0; // Add null terminator
print_null_terminated_string(message); // or just printf("%s", message)
```

Or:

```
while(toupper(ch = getchar()) != '\n')
{
    message[i] = ch;
    i++;
}
size_t length = i;
print_string_with_known_length(message, length); // or printf("%.*s", length, message) if you want to be fancy
```